# Wrong number of lifetime parameters when using a modified `Chars` iterator

Tags: iterator, rust, traits, lifetime

I want to implement the `IntoIterator` trait for a struct containing a `String`. The iterator is based on the `chars()` iterator, is supposed to count the `'1'` chars and accumulate the result. This is a simplified version of what I got so far:

```
use std::iter::Map;
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let str_struct = StringStruct { system_string: String::from("1101") };
    for a in str_struct {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}

struct StringStruct {
    system_string: String
}

impl IntoIterator for StringStruct {
    type Item = u32;
    type IntoIter = Map<Chars, Fn(char) -> u32>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let count = 0;
        return self.system_string.chars().map(|c| match c {
            Some('1') => {
                count += 1;
                return Some(count);
            },
            Some(chr) => return Some(count),
            None => return None
        });
    }
}
```

Expected output: `1, 2, 2, 3`

This fails with:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:17:25
   |
17 |     type IntoIter = Map<Chars, Fn(char) -> u32>;
   |                         ^^^^^ expected 1 lifetime parameter
```

The chars iterator should have the same lifetime as the `StringStruct::system_string`, but I have no idea how to express this or if this approach is viable at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question you asked, I'd recommend to `impl IntoIterator for &StringStruct` (a **reference** to a `StringStruct` instead of the struct directly). The code would look like this:

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a StringStruct {
    type Item = u32;
    type IntoIter = Map<Chars<'a>, Fn(char) -> u32>;
    // ...
}
```

---

However, you will notice many **more errors** that have a different origin afterwards. The next error that pops up is that `Fn(char) -> u32` does not have a constant size at compile time.

The problem is that you try to name the type of your closure by writing `Fn(char) -> u32`. But this is *not* the type of your closure, but merely a trait which is implemented by the closure. The type of a closure **can't be named** (sometimes called "Voldemort type").

This means that, right now, you can't specify the type of a `Map<_, _>` object. This is a known issue; the recently accepted `impl Trait`-RFC might offer a workaround for cases like this. But right now, it's not possible, sorry.

**So how to solve it then?** You need to create your own type that implements `Iterator` and use it instead of `Map<_, _>`. Note that you can still use the `Chars` iterator. Here is the full solution:

```
struct StringStructIter<'a> {
    chars: Chars<'a>,
    count: u32,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for StringStructIter<'a> {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
         self.chars.next().map(|c| {
            if c == '1' {
                self.count += 1;
            }
            self.count
        })
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a StringStruct {
    type Item = u32;
    type IntoIter = StringStructIter<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
         StringStructIter {
             chars: self.system_string.chars(),
             count: 0,
         }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let str_struct = StringStruct { system_string: String::from("1101") };
    for a in &str_struct {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}
```

---

*And just a small note*: an explicit `return` when not necessary is considered bad style in Rust. Better stick to rule and write idiomatic code by removing `return` whenever possible ;-)

Comment: I'm newby with Rust. How can I use your solution?  `for a in ?????? { println!("{}", a); }` ?

Comment: I want to test your solution but I don't see how to do this. `fn main() {
    let str_struct = StringStructIter{ How to do from "1101" ? };
    for a in str_struct {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}`

Comment: @LeMoussel I added the remaining code, I hope everything should be clear now!